# Delphi 7: objects on frame aren't rendered (bug?)

Tags: delphi, object, label, frame, invisible

I'm using a frame to cover several objects on a parent form. The frame contains a progress bar, a label and a button. When I activate the frame, only the progress bar is rendered. The label and the button stay invisible. Setting .enable + .visible to true in the code upon showing the frame doesn't work either. I can see the objects perfectly fine in the IDE. They disappear only at runtime.

I read on this thread that there seems to be a bug in Delphi 7 that might cause this behavior, but I'm not sure:

http://www.delphigroups.info/2/7/734850.html

Is there a workaround to get Delphi to render all of the frame's objects?

Update: dfm-code for frame

```
object Frame2: TFrame2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 528
  Height = 116
  TabOrder = 0
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 32
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 72
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object ProgressBar1: TProgressBar
    Left = 8
    Top = 32
    Width = 473
    Height = 24
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

Comment: can you dump the *.dfm file for the frame here please? I've wrote serveral D7 applications using frames(in stead of forms) and never got this issue...

Comment: Is the button a TSpeedButton or something that derives from TGraphicControl?

Comment: You're using the frame to *cover* the other controls? But then you say you *activate* the frame — what does that mean? Then you say you *show* the frame, but since the frame covers the other components, why is it any surprise that showing the frame makes the controls disappear? They're covered!

Comment: You're asking for a workaround. What happened when you tried the workaround listed at the link you provided?

Comment: @Dorin: I updated the description with the dfm-code.

Comment: Andreas: No, it's a normal TButton
Rob: First the main window is shown, once the user clicks a button, the frame is supposed to overlay the main window with new options to keep everything within a single window. It's not about disappearing controls (that works fine), but those that don't appear in the frame (the new ones).
As for the linked in solution: This is far beyond my expertise. I just started learning Pascal.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish, I've created a simple application 1 form, 1 frame(with 1 label, 1 button, 1 progress bar -- in this order), on form's create event, I create the frame and set the form as parent with Frame.Parent := Self(* form *); everything works nicely, maybe Frame.BringToFront is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Dorin: BringToFront didn't work either. I restarted a test project from scratch and there everything worked as expected. May be my code throws a rock in Delphi's way, but I'll find that out when I'll copy it bit by bit into the newly working project. Thanks to all you guys for your help :)

Comment: @Zerobinary99 I hope you get to the end of it, it's really annoying when this type of issues appear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the error and I'm quite ashamed since it's a rather obvious one:

Upon button click the frame is being rendered including all its objects, however, the click also initializes a CPU-intense function. Since this was early code, I hadn't implemented threading yet, so the function froze the gui-rendering and thus prevented some objects to appear. This was "fixed" when I commented out the function. I was also thrown off by the fact, that the progress bar on the frame not just appeared, but kept updating despite the CPU-usage.

Thanks again to all of you who replied.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your components into a Panel.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that! Same issues appeared though for reasons I explained below.